# If $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{n}{u_n}=1$, what can we say about $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{u_n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

If $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}\frac{n}{u_n}=1$, can we prove that series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{u_n}$ converges,  doesn't converge or it's indefinite?

I know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u_n}$ diverges by the comparing theorem. But I didn't find an explicit theorem about the alternate series.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Play with $$\frac{n}{u_n} = 1 + (-1)^n\varepsilon_n. $$

Comment: A series may only be convergent or non-convergent, what does it mean for a series to be *indefinite*?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Given a problem of this sort, it is possible that it could converge or not, given certain sequences.

Comment: @IsaacBrowne Not = divergence. there is no third category

Comment: @zhw Could I not say that it depends on the sequence. Here is a scenario. A random series $u_n$ may diverge or it may converge. It depends on what the sequence is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$\dfrac1{u_n}
= \dfrac1{n}+(-1)^n\dfrac1{n\ln(n)}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^M (-1)^n\dfrac1{u_n}
&=\sum_{n=1}^M (-1)^n(\dfrac1{n}+(-1)^n\dfrac1{n\ln(n)})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^M (-1)^n\dfrac1{n}+\sum_{n=1}^M\dfrac1{n\ln(n)}\\
\end{array}
$

and the first sum converges
while the second sum diverges,
so the sum itself diverges.

Therefore you can not say.

Comment: Thank you. I think your method is a specific example of the way Daniel Fisher proposed in the comment $\frac{n}{u_n} = 1 + (-1)^n\varepsilon_n$.